# angular - forkjoin requests being duplicated

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm using `forkjoin` to retrieve some data from the API in order to populate a list in component's `ngOnInit`. When the requests are made, the data will be cached in a `Map<url, data>()` which be accessed later, so that no unnecessary requests are made.

However, I have noticed these requests are being duplicated.

Here is the component .ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-orders',
    templateUrl: './orders.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./orders.component.css']
})
export class OrdersComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    ...
    private subscription: Subscription;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.subscription = this.shopService.getPreferencesAsObservable().pipe(
            filter(preferences => !!preferences),
            tap(() => {
                this.isDeliverySlotsActive = this.shopService.isDeliverySlotsActive();
            }),
            switchMap(() => 
                forkJoin([
                        this.getInitialPendingOrders(true), 
                        this.getInitialPendingOrders(false),
                        this.getInitialDeliveredOrders(true),
                        this.getInitialDeliveredOrders(false),
                        this.getInitialCancelledOrders(true),
                        this.getInitialCancelledOrders(false)
                    ]
                )
            )
          ).subscribe(res => {
                /* do stuff with response data */
        });
    }

    getInitialPendingOrders(hasSlots: boolean){
        return this.apiService.fetchShopOrders("status=PENDING&status=FULFILLED" + (hasSlots ? "&only_slots=true" : ''));
    }

    getInitialDeliveredOrders(hasSlots: boolean){
        return this.apiService.fetchShopOrders("status=DELIVERED" + (hasSlots ? "&only_slots=true" : ''));
    }

    getInitialCancelledOrders(hasSlots: boolean){
        return this.apiService.fetchShopOrders("status=CANCELLED" + (hasSlots ? "&only_slots=true" : ''));
    }
    ...
}
```

And the API manager:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ApiManagerService {

    ...
    private readonly url = "...";
    public ordersResponseCache = new Map<string, OrdersList>();

    fetchShopOrders(status: string, quantity: number = 100) {       
        const endpoint = this.url + "order/" + this.webzineId + "/order/?per_page=" + quantity + "&" + status;
        const ordersFromCache: OrdersList = this.ordersResponseCache.get(endpoint);
        if (ordersFromCache) {
            return of(ordersFromCache);
        }
        const response = this.http.get<OrdersList>(endpoint).pipe(shareReplay(1));
        response.subscribe(orders => this.ordersResponseCache.set(endpoint, orders));
        return response; 
    }
    ...
}
```

I reckon this behaviour is happening because of the subscription inside `fetchShopOrders()`. However, I'm not really sure what to do to avoid this subscription, since I need to save the response data in the cache. How can rxjs help me in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're subscribing twice... don't do that. do this instead:

```
// cache the shared observable, not the response
// shareReplay is already holding a cache of the response.
public ordersResponseCache = new Map<string, Observable<OrdersList>>();

fetchShopOrders(status: string, quantity: number = 100) {       
    const endpoint = this.url + "order/" + this.webzineId + "/order/?per_page=" + quantity + "&" + status;
    const ordersFromCache: Observable<OrdersList> = this.ordersResponseCache.get(endpoint);
    if (ordersFromCache) {
        return ordersFromCache;
    }
    const req = this.http.get<OrdersList>(endpoint).pipe(
      shareReplay(1),
      catchError(e => { // don't cache errors
        this.ordersResponseCache.delete(endpoint);
        return throwError(e);
      })
    );
    this.ordersResponseCache.set(endpoint, req);
    return req; 
}
```

Comment: Yep, this did the trick! Thank you sir. I suspected it was due to the double subscription. By the way, do you mind provinding a brief explanation of your answer? As an rxjs rookie it's a bit tough to understand why this works as opposed to what I was doing.

Comment: the `shareReplay` operator maintains a cache of the response. it's essentially an observable cache operator. so you're just caching that cache rather than double subscribing and manually caching the response.